# What's the default /etc/network/interfaces?

Tags: networking

I messed up my network configuration. Can anyone help me and copy the default `/etc/network/interfaces`?

Comment: More about loopback : http://askubuntu.com/questions/247625/what-is-the-loopback-device-and-how-do-i-use-it

Answer (score 40, accepted):

**For eth0 with dhcp:**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

**For eth0 static:**

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo eth0
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
iface eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.10.33
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    broadcast 192.168.10.255
    network 192.168.10.0
    gateway 192.168.10.254 
dns-nameservers 192.168.10.254
```

link:
http://www.iasptk.com/ubuntu/20202-ubuntu-server-networking-configuration-dhcp-address-static-ip-address-second-ip-address-or-virtual-ip-address

Comment: So what do I do if mine has no primary network interface, just has iface lo inet loopback ??

Comment: You have to add a primary (dhcp OR static) adding the lines above

Comment: What if I don't add 'network' and 'broadcast' entries? Will the default to the reasonable values?

Comment: As reference, this answer shows [how to find the network device name](https://askubuntu.com/a/976282/625092) - as `eth0` is no longer that common.

Answer (score 14):

Mine looks like:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Answer (score 6):

Following the [Debian network configuration page](https://wiki.debian.org/NetworkConfiguration), if you're just using DHCP then all you need is something like:

```
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the default contents of `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).
source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```