# Trying to configure a loopback network interface but its not working

Tags: networking, interface

I've read the other posts..however I still have not fixed my interface. I have the following:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet static
post-up /sbin/ethtool -s eth0 speed 100 duplex full autoneg off
address 109.169.67.61
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 109.169.67.1
dns-nameservers 87.117.198.200 87.117.237.100 87.117.196.200

auto eth0:0
allow-hotplug eth0:0
iface eth1 inet static
        address 109.169.67.138
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:1
allow-hotplug eth0:1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 109.169.67.139
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:2
allow-hotplug eth0:2
iface eth1 inet static
        address 109.169.67.140
        netmask 255.255.255.0

auto eth0:3
allow-hotplug eth0:3
iface eth1 inet static
        address 109.169.67.166
        netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried just using the default Ubuntu interfaces config and seeing if  that works? [Here](http://askubuntu.com/a/214179/400278) is the default config.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I found the solution:

```
ifconfig eth0:0 109.169.67.138 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ifconfig eth0:1 109.169.67.139 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ifconfig eth0:2 109.169.67.140 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
ifconfig eth0:3 109.169.67.166 netmask 255.255.255.0 up
```