# Virtual box issue with /etc/network/interfaces

Tags: server, virtualbox, localhost

I'm trying to run a pentest server (2014 in a box challenge: https://www.cyberchallenge.com.au/) on virtual box. I've set up a static ip in etc/network/interfaces as such:

```
#auto lo
auto eth0
#iface eth0 inet dhcp
iface eth0inet static

address 10.0.05
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 10.0.0.0
broadcast 10.1.2.255
gateway 10.0.0.1
```

When I boot the server I am shown the IP to connect to, however when I load the IP in chrome it will timeout. When I try and set up DHCP the server gives me blank IP.

I'm new to servers so it's quite possible I'm doing something ridiculously silly, sorry if it's a simple fix!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have few typos. Probably what you wanted is:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.5
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 10.0.0.0
  broadcast 10.0.0.255
  gateway 10.0.0.1
```

If your version of ubuntu is 16.04 (your network interface might not even be `eth0`), in this case you might need to:

- [What's the default /etc/network/interfaces?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/214170/whats-the-default-etc-network-interfaces)

Comment: It looks like i made the typo on the post; the interfaces file seems to match what you've written. How do I know whether I should use wlan0 or eth0? I'm using my host machine (chrome in windows) to try and load the server ip in the browser. Is it possible to set up DHCP? Should I try and change my network adaptor settings? Sorry for the questions!