# Reset network configuration

Tags: 16.04, server, rescue-mode

Recently I messed up the network settings for my Ubuntu 16.04 machine. It does  not load the network when it boots normally. Before this, I did `ip addr flush eth0` instead of `eth1`. The machine is now in rescue mode and I have the normal disk mounted to `/mnt`.

How would I reset the network settings? The machine is a dedicated server from OVH so I only have remote control.

Answer (score 1):

If you can access a terminal on that server, try to update the network settings like [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/214179/400278) in that server's `/etc/network/interfaces` file.

Answer (score 0):

The -r option explicitly releases the lease

`$ sudo dhclient -r`

Now obtain fresh IP address using DHCP on Linux:

`$ sudo dhclient`

For me restarting the networkmanager works fine but the above commands are almost equivalent of ipconfig -release/renew commands of windows to reset the network.