# nVidia 430 Vitesse gigabit ethernet LAN support in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, nvidia, ethernet

UPDATE:

[apparmor output with dmesg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ppc1u.jpg)

Had to take existing Ubuntu 14.04 installation running with a `Gigabyte GA-M57SLI-S4 Rev 1.1` motherboard and move it to an older `Gigabyte GA-K8N51GMF-9` motherboard scenario.

The `GA-K8N51GMF-9` has a `Vitesse 8201` gigabit ethernet LAN chip.

["Onboard LAN" excerpt from GA-K8N51GMF-9 manual](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0srM0.png)

[Highlighted LAN section of GA-K8N51GMF-9 block diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBG04.png)

The `GA-K8N51GMF-9` runs an `nVidia nForce 430` chipset.

The system is set up to get an IP from DHCP but cannot get an IP on bootup.

I set the unit up to use SSH keys so ethernet is critical and my debugging options are limited but I do have physical access to the machine and one limited account (not even `sudo`!) login I can use.

I've reset the BIOS to defaults, both optimised and safe. Neither helps.

[lspci (apologies if too blurry)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP9Ca.jpg)

[dmesg (apologies if too blurry)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DPCst.jpg)

Does Ubuntu 14.04 support the `Vitesse 8201` chip?

Comment: Let's start with: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` and also: `dmesg | grep eth` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Added UPDATE. Looks like there may be `apparmor` issus with several network-related files. Maybe hard drive corruption is the overall culprit?

Comment: Interesting. How do you have networking set up? In `/etc/network/interfaces`? May we please see the contents?

Comment: @chili555, I'm not at the machine just now but I'm pretty sure from looking at `/etc/network/interfaces` last night, it's standard out of the box. The only variation was that I was giving it a consistent IP through MAC recognition assignment in my router, but that should not be a factor and it's in a different location now as well. Looking on the interwebs for the defaults example, I'll know when I see it ... yep, AFAIK `/etc/network/interfaces` is the DHCP version here: https://askubuntu.com/a/214179/770153

Comment: Please notice that your interface is now eth1, not eth0. Please change the file and see if it all now works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70023/discussion-between-pd-au-and-chili555). ... at least I would but I don't seem to be able to log into chat.

Comment: I noticed the change to eth1 though I don't understand why it did that. Regardless, I currently don't have permission to edit /etc/network/interfaces due to aforementioned lack of SSH ability. Vicious cycle? Can I force Ubuntu to use eth0 again through any boot param or recevery mode, perhaps?

Comment: I thought from your screen pictures that you had physical access; no?

Comment: If you have physical access, can’t you sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces and simply change to eth1 and reboot?

Comment: Looking at your apparmor, it appears that you are running Network Manager and a desktop environment. Is that the case?

Comment: I have physical access but not sudo. It's not a desktop environment.

Comment: Without sudo permission, I am unaware of any other alternatives. There is probably a udev rule that you can remove, with sudo, or you can amend the `interfaces` file, with sudo or you might be able to simply `sudo dhclient eth1` again, with sudo.

Comment: No worries @chili555. Thanks so much for trying to help! I think I'll be able to resolve it by yanking the storage and plugging it into a portable HDD reader from which I can use the mega helpful DiskInternals Linux Reader from within Windows to change the `/etc/network/interfaces`. Another option would be to run a Linux live USB over the top of it and edit the file that way. Yep, I know, Linux people don't want to believe it's that easy to 'hack' into Linux, but I'm glad that it is :) Physical access being enough of a barrier in many SOHO scenarios. Thanks again!

Comment: With physical access and a live Linux CD, I think *any* system is vulnerable. It actually sounds like a good plan.

Comment: Well, unfortunately the best laid plans ... edited `/etc/network/interfaces` to use `eth1` and still no network :(

Comment: It's back! Finally. The eth0 to eth1 fix actually stuck this time, seemingly. Never been so happy to get a degraded RAID array email notification! Thanks so very much for your persistance and help @chili555 !